# WCF Type 'System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute' is not defined

Tags: wcf, wcf-authentication

I am following this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515342.aspx#Y1283) that shows how to implement a WCF authentication Service. I have done exactly step by step as detailed.  But after adding all the proxy classes when I try to build the project, it gives me some 68 Errors and few are listed below.  I don't know what I am doing wrong here.  Clearly I think I am missing some Imports in my class or some attribute in app.config file.  I may be wrong.

```
Type 'System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute' is not defined.
Type 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute' is not defined.
Type 'System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute' is not defined.
Type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress' is not defined.
```

All the three application services(authentication, Roles, Profile services) compile appropriately as shown in the walkthrough article.  I was trying to build Single-Sign on Mechanism through WCF Authentication service.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you add reference to system.ServiceModel?

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling for at least .NET 3.0? If your build target is .NET 2.0 the types won't be defined